# Observable Vs Completable Why is the Completable task not being called?

Tags: java, rx-java

So guys newish to RX Java I have a question.

In my expedition of learning the beast that is RXJava this is my class under test.

```
public class PollingLoop {

public static <T> Observable<T> buildObservable(
    final int interval,
    final TimeUnit timeUnit,
    final int maxJitter,
    final Scheduler scheduler,
    final Supplier<Observable<T>> scheduledTask) {

    if (maxJitter <= 0) throw new IllegalArgumentException("Jitter must be greater than 0");

    final Random randomJitter = new Random();
    return Observable.timer(interval, timeUnit, scheduler)
        .map(x -> {
            System.out.println("Flat map jitter");
            return randomJitter.nextInt(maxJitter);
        })
        .flatMap(jitter -> {
            System.out.println("Flat map timer");
            return Observable.timer(jitter, timeUnit, scheduler);
        })
        .flatMap(ignored -> {
            System.out.println("Flat map task");
            return scheduledTask.get();
        })
        .retry()
        .repeat();
}

public static <T> Completable buildCompletable(
    final int interval,
    final TimeUnit timeUnit,
    final int maxJitter,
    final Scheduler scheduler,
    final Supplier<Completable> scheduledTask) {

    if (maxJitter <= 0) throw new IllegalArgumentException("Jitter must be greater than 0");

    final Random randomJitter = new Random();
    return Observable.timer(interval, timeUnit, scheduler)
        .map(x -> {
            System.out.println("Flat map jitter");
            return randomJitter.nextInt(maxJitter);
        })
        .flatMapCompletable(jitter -> {
            System.out.println("Flat map timer");
            return Completable.timer(jitter, timeUnit, scheduler);
        })
        .flatMapCompletable(ignored -> {
            System.out.println("Flat map task that is not called");
            return scheduledTask.get();
        })
        .retry()
        .repeat()
        .toCompletable();
}
}
```

From a test when i test the delay of execution of an Observable I get the output

```
Flat map jitter
Flat map timer
Flat map task //(observable is being called)
```

But when i test the delay of execution of an Completable I get the output

```
Flat map jitter
Flat map timer
```

//(The completable task is not being called)

What am i doing wrong? Why is the Completable task not being called from within buildCompletable?

Here are the test (written in spock)

```
def 'should delay execution of observable'() {
    given:
    def subscriber = new TestSubscriber<>()
    def scheduler = new TestScheduler()
    def supplier = Mock Supplier

    supplier.get() >> Observable.just(true)

    when:
    PollingLoop.buildObservable(100, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, 1, scheduler, supplier).subscribe(subscriber)
    scheduler.advanceTimeBy(101, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)

    then:
    subscriber.assertValueCount(1)
    subscriber.assertValue(true)
}

    def 'should delay execution of completable'(){
    given:
    def subscriber = new TestSubscriber<>()
    def scheduler = new TestScheduler()
    def supplier = Mock Supplier
    supplier.get() >> Completable.complete()

    when:
    PollingLoop.buildCompletable(100, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, 1, scheduler, supplier).subscribe(subscriber)

    scheduler.advanceTimeBy(1001, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
enter code here
    then:
    1 * supplier.get()
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure how it is even compiled. the first `flatMapCompletable` returns `Completable` which doesn't have `flatMapCompletable` method (which make sense)

Comment: it had compiled without any issues but it didnt chain from the first flatMapCompletable to the 2nd one. 

To fix I had to go timer() -> map() -> flatMap() -> flatMapCompletable() -> retry -> ......

Comment: I don't understand, do we miss here additional code? it's a compilation error when I copy paste it, please provide full code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result of your first `flatMapCompletable()` is a completable, as that is what you are returning. However, that completable will never emit a value (by definition) so there is no value for the subsequent `flatMapCompletable()` to map.

Since your first `Completable` doesn't emit a value, you will need to bind the next step using the `andThen()` operator or something similar.

Your code compiles because the `flatMapCompletable()` operator has a signature of `Observable<Long>`. You will need to put the `andThen()` operator inside the `flatMapCompletable()` function.

Comment: cheers @Bob I found the problem shortly after but you are right.